# Filling rows from calendar table with previous values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to SQL, coming over from Python and R, and using Spark SQL with Databricks. I'm trying to complete a basic query and would appreciate guidance, especially guidance that explains the underlying concepts of SQL as they relate to my question.

I have a calendar table with complete, consecutive dates, and a data table with `date_added`, `user_id`, `sales`, and `price` columns. The data table has incomplete dates, since not every user is active on every date. Below are examples of each table.

Calendar Table

```
date
2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-04
2020-01-05
2020-01-06
```

Data Table

```
date_added     user_id    sales    price
2020-01-02     01         1        4.00
2020-01-05     01         3        4.00
2020-01-02     02         1        5.00
2020-01-03     02         1        5.00
2020-01-05     02         2        5.00
2020-01-03     03         2        1.00
2020-01-05     03         5        1.00
```

I am looking to create a new table, where every calendar table date within a certain range (the *active* dates) is defined for every user, and null values for all columns except the sales column are filled by the following value in that column. Something along these lines:

```
date           user_id    sales    price         
2020-01-02     01         1        4.00
2020-01-03     01         null     4.00
2020-01-04     01         null     4.00
2020-01-05     01         3        4.00
2020-01-02     02         1        5.00
2020-01-03     02         1        5.00
2020-01-04     02         null     5.00
2020-01-05     02         2        5.00
2020-01-02     03         null     1.00
2020-01-03     03         2        1.00
2020-01-04     03         null     1.00
2020-01-05     03         5        1.00
```

Any guidance is appreciated on how I might proceed to this output. I've tried to use a LEFT JOIN on the dates, but without success. I know that the UNION operator is used to concatenate tables on top of one another, but don't know how I would apply that method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross join the users with the calendar table then left join with data table:

```scala
spark.sql("""
  SELECT  date, dates.user_id, sales, COALESCE(data.price, dates.price) AS price
  FROM    (
      SELECT  user_id, price, date
      FROM    (SELECT user_id, FIRST(price) as price FROM data_table GROUP BY user_id)
      CROSS JOIN calender_table
      WHERE   date >= (SELECT MIN(date_added) FROM data_table)
      AND     date <= (SELECT MAX(date_added) FROM data_table)
  )   dates
  LEFT JOIN data_table data
  ON      dates.user_id = data.user_id
  AND     dates.date = data.date_added
""").show()
```

Output:

```text
+----------+-------+-----+-----+
|date      |user_id|sales|price|
+----------+-------+-----+-----+
|2020-01-02|01     |1    |4.0  |
|2020-01-03|01     |null |4.0  |
|2020-01-04|01     |null |4.0  |
|2020-01-05|01     |3    |4.0  |
|2020-01-02|02     |1    |5.0  |
|2020-01-03|02     |1    |5.0  |
|2020-01-04|02     |null |5.0  |
|2020-01-05|02     |2    |5.0  |
|2020-01-02|03     |null |1.0  |
|2020-01-03|03     |2    |1.0  |
|2020-01-04|03     |null |1.0  |
|2020-01-05|03     |5    |1.0  |
+----------+-------+-----+-----+
```

You can also generate the dates without using a calendar table using [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence) function. See my other answer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#sequence).

Answer (score 1):

Let your original dataframe as `df1`. Then you can get the `min`, `max` date for each `id` and let it as `df2'.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('user_id').orderBy(f.desc('date_added'))

df2 = df1.groupBy('user_id') \
  .agg(f.sequence(f.min('date_added'), f.max('date_added')).alias('date_added')) \
  .withColumn('date_added', f.explode('date_added'))

df2.join(df, ['user_id', 'date_added'], 'left') \
   .withColumn('price', f.first('price').over(w)) \
   .orderBy('user_id', 'date_added') \
   .show()

+-------+----------+-----+-----+
|user_id|date_added|sales|price|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+
|      1|2020-01-02|    1|  4.0|
|      1|2020-01-03| null|  4.0|
|      1|2020-01-04| null|  4.0|
|      1|2020-01-05|    3|  4.0|
|      2|2020-01-02|    1|  5.0|
|      2|2020-01-03|    1|  5.0|
|      2|2020-01-04| null|  5.0|
|      2|2020-01-05|    2|  5.0|
|      3|2020-01-03|    2|  1.0|
|      3|2020-01-04| null|  1.0|
|      3|2020-01-05|    5|  1.0|
+-------+----------+-----+-----+
```